# Ban by IP and auto redirect to HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block access to the website for certain IP addresses. For this I have a file `ipblacklist.conf` with list of IPs in the following format one line per IP:

```
Require not ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then in the `httpd.config` I have this:

```
<Location />
   <RequireAll>
      Require all granted
      Include ipblacklist.conf
   </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

This works fine; however, I also have automatic redirect to `https` with the help of `mod-rewrite`, at the end of `httpd.config`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDown
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Both of these features work fine, however, when I visit `http` page from banned ip, it doesn't show `403` error right the way, it first redirects to `https` then it shows `403`. Is there a way avoid redirection banned IPs to `https`

Comment: Modify your RewriteCond to check the IP address against the map before redirecting to HTTPS

Comment: Using mod_rewrite for this is rather inefficient. I would use mod_alias for a simple HTTP to HTTPS redirect and place the blacklist on the HTTP configuration, too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below might help.

In your httpd.conf file, add the following lines to create the map:

```
RewriteMap ipblacklist txt:/etc/ipblacklist.txt
```

Modify your RewriteCond to check the IP address against the map before redirecting to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond ${ipblacklist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !=1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In the example I provided, `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` is used as an argument in the RewriteMap to check the client's IP address against the banned IP addresses in the ipblacklist.txt file. If the IP address is found in the map, the condition ${ipblacklist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !=1 is true and the request is not redirected to HTTPS, instead it will shows the 403 error.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work, unfortunately it requires to have and maintain 2 different lists. Unless do the 403 error via mod-rewrite itself. Either way, the server would have to check ip twice for each request...